# Recursive minimum with negative numbers

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to make recursive function to sort an array in ascending order. So for example given the input

```
5 | 12 31 48 25 50
```

The output must be

```
5 | 12 25 31 48 50
```

The number at the beginning is the size of the array.

---

I have produced this code (it must use recursive functions):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int minimo(int *A, int lung) {

 if (lung == 1)
  return A[0];

 int k = minimo(A+1, lung-1);
 return A[0] < k ? A[0] : k;

}

//sort function
void ordina(int *A, int lung) {

 if (lung > 0) { 

  cout << minimo(A, lung) << " ";
  ordina(A+1, lung-1);

 } 

}


int main() {

    int lung;
    int A[100];
    cin >> lung;

    for(int i = 0; i < lung; i++) { 
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    //print array
    ordina(A, lung);

  return 0;
}
```

The code works pretty well with the input above but when I try with negative input formats such as:

```
7 | 73 49 12 37 23 -14 -14
```

The output is:

```
7 | -14 -14 -14 -14 -14 -14 -14
```

Could you please explain me why?

---

The `ordina` function calls itself; I decrease the length and I increase `A+1` so that the min won't be calculate more than once on the same slice of array. Also

```
return A[0] < k ? A[0] : k;
```

Here I check if the item in A[0] is lower than k but k changes each time because the recursive function has different variables on the stack each "cycle". I can't really understand why the -14 input is not working. Any idea?

Comment: You don't swap element, you only print minimum values of smaller and smaller array.

Comment: When I enter 5 | 12 31 48 25 50, it outputs 12 25 25 25 50.  Which is what I would expect from the code - it always prints the lowest value in the subarray.

Comment: `minimo` is working, it is `ordina` which have issue (and should not call `minimo` BTW).

Comment: If you try to put a negative number you'll get an error.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi You should read Paul's comment more closely. His output is what your code produces and is not the result you said it produces. It repeats the value 25 three times.

Comment: Well I think I have understood where my problem is. I shouldn't simply print the lowest number, but I should swap the lowest and get rid of it. Shouldn't I? In fact this should be why I have -14 as output and @PaulBentley has 3 times 25

Comment: So you should have a function which return index of min value (and not directly the min value).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes now I have understood, I am working on it. I need the index of the min so that I can do a swap!

Comment: And when returning the index, remembering to increment it as you recurse back out (deep into the recursion, element 0 becomes element 1 when you return, which becomes element 2 when you return, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the position (incrementing before returning), swapping when necessary.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int minimo(int* A, int length) {
  if (length ==1) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    int position = minimo(A+1,length-1)+1;
    if (A[0]<A[position]) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      std::swap(A[0],A[position]);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}


void ordina(int* A,int length) {
  if (length>0) {
    cout<< A[minimo(A,length)]<< " ";

    ordina(A+1,length-1);
  }
}


int main() {

    int lung;
    int A[100];
    cin >> lung;

    for(int i = 0; i < lung; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    //print array
    ordina(A, lung);

  return 0;
}
```

However, it always returns position 0, so this isn't the codes final form. Evolving code to not return anything:

```
void minimo(int* A, int length) {
  if (length > 1) {
    minimo(A+1,length-1);
    if (A[0]>A[1]) {
      std::swap(A[0],A[1]);
    }
  }
}


void ordina(int* A,int length) {
  if (length>0) {
    minimo(A,length);
    cout<< A[0]<< " ";

    ordina(A+1,length-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to write an answers by myself, I came up with basically the same code. The minimo function should me void because I don't really need the index at all. Thank you Paul!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you remove the first element of the array, instead of the smallest one after iteration:

```
ordina(A+1, lung-1);
```

What you can do is simply swap the elements if the right one is bigger. The min element finally goes to the beginning of the array A[0]

It is as simple as BubbleSort:

```
int minimo(int *A, int lung) {

if (lung == 1)
    return A[0];

minimo(A+1, lung-1);   //YOU DON'T NEED THE RESULT
if (A[0] > A[1])
    std::swap(A[0], A[1])
return A[0];
```

}